# 7-zip Add to "filename" but in ULTRA?

Tags: 7-zip, context-menu

7-zip has a right click menu to add to archive using the filename which is great. But it compress it using "normal" compression. To use "ultra" you have to do it manually.

Officially there's no way to do this as confirmed by the creator:
https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/d2fb5d59/

But how about an alternative method to add the command to the right click menu? I'm pretty sure this has to be possible.

Comment: You can do that in command prompt instead of context menu. 7zip uses COM interface to use context menu and it can be only changed in 7zip source code.

Comment: Command prompt would be slower if have to type the whole command each time then the GUI would be faster. I need a way to bind the command or a bat to the right click context menu somehow.

Comment: Damn, i thought it was possible. I guess there's no solution then.